# How do I simplify integrating factor?

Tags: problem-solving

I have obtained following integrating factor from ODE ($y^{\prime} + a(x) = g(x)$):

$ e^{\,A(x)} \:\:=\:\ e^{- \ln |\cos(x)|+c}$

where $ e^{\,A(x)}$ is integrating factor and $A(x) = \int a(x)\,\mathrm{d}x$.

$e^{- \ln |\cos(x)|+c}$ should equal to  $ \:\frac{1}{\cos x}\:$.

How do I simplify the equation to $ \:\frac{1}{\cos x}\:$?

Thanks.
⁡

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use that $$-\log(\cos(x))=\log\frac{1}{\cos(x)}$$

Comment: Thanks. I see, and why is the constant $c$ gone? Sorry, if this is a stupid question but I had some problem understanding why $e^{\, \ln x} = x$...

Comment: It can be written as $$e^{-c}e^{-\ln(\cos(x))}$$

Comment: But isn't it   $e^{-c} \cdot \dfrac{1}{cos(x)}$  then?

Comment: Yes, this is true.

Comment: It's just that in the school we ignored the $e^{-c}$ completely and the teacher just wrote that it all equals to $1/cos(x)$ only. I haven't asked because as usual it's fast lecturing and now we can't find out why... Thanks anyway, for you help :).